# conserve order in retrieving data from DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
select id, name 
from contributor 
where id in (select contributor_id 
             from procedure_contributor 
             where procedure_id = 13);
```

this query returns:

```
id   name
_____________
25  "Steven"
5   "Sergio"
4   "Nadine"
21  "Sami"
3   "Nicolas"
23  "Samuel"
17  "Sarrah"
22  "Andrea"
24  "Ramos"
```

I wanna get the ids as they are returned from the nested query:

```
select contributor_id from procedure_contributor where procedure_id = 13
```

which returns:

```
contributor_id 
________________
"3"
"22"
"17"
"4"
"5"
"21"
"23"
"24"
"25"
```

Is there a way to that?

Comment: The values are not returned in any order from the sub-query. Rows in a relational database are **NOT** "sorted". Without an `order by` the database is free to return them in any order it sees fit. And an `order by` in a sub-query used for an `IN` will be ignored anyway by the main query. The **only** (really: the _only_) way you can guarantee a specific sort order is to use an `order by`. You either need a column in `contributor` to do the sorting. Or one in `procedure_contributor` - but then you need a join to be able to sort the outer query

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, this can be the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, one way to do it would be to add a  row_number() to your subquery. A 'IN' will no longer work so you will need to join on it and then order by this row_number().

But really, you're just showing your results in a random order. The next time you run this query you can get your items in another order. So the proper fix is to add an order by and sort on a column you want.

Answer (score 0):

The values are not returned in any order from the sub-query. Rows in a relational database are NOT "sorted". Without an order by the database is free to return them in any order it sees fit. And an order by in a sub-query used for an IN will be ignored anyway by the main query. The only (really: the only) way you can guarantee a specific sort order is to use an order by. You either need a column in contributor to do the sorting. Or one in procedure_contributor - but then you need a join to be able to sort the outer query

*it's the @a_horse_with_no_name's comment!